# Проблема с label1.Text в UserControl1.cs

Tags: c#

Я создал UserControl1.cs. В этот компонент передается два значения, которые суммируются и выводятся в lable1 этого компонента. Но когда доходит в методе Am() до

```
  label1.Text = c.ToString();
```

то появляется ошибка: *Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта. NullReferenceException не обработано*.

Код формы:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace bred4
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UserControl1 fff = new UserControl1(6,3);
        fff.Am();
    }
    private void userControl11_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
}
```

Код UserControl:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace bred4
{
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public UserControl1(float aa, float bb)
    {
        a = aa;
        b = bb;
    }
    static float a, b; 
    float c;
    private void UserControl1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       c = a + b;
       label1.Text = c.ToString();
    }
    public void Am()
  {
         c = a + b;
         label1.Text = c.ToString(); //ошибка в этом месте
  }
}
}
```

Если использовать метод button1_Click() , т.е. нажать на кнопку, то сложение происходит и ошибки не возникает. В чем причина и как решить проблему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по исключению, в момент выполнения метода `label1 == null`.

Просто в *другом* конструкторе `UserControl1` отсутствует вызов метода `InitializeComponent()`, который и занимается созданием элементов управления на контроле, в т.ч. `label1`.

Но даже после исправления кода суммирование отображаться не станет, т.к. будет происходить создание `UserControl1`, выполнение Am() и сборка мусорщиком, без всякого отображения на форме. Тут скорее стоит просто выполнить метод Am() у уже созданного контрола на форме (в данном случае, в Form_Load()):

```
userControl11.A = 6;
userControl11.B = 3;
userControl11.Am();
```

Для этого предварительно необходимо добавить свойства `A` и `B` в `UserControl1`:

```
public float A
{
    get { return a; }
    set { a = value; }
}

// B аналогично
```

Comment: а для этого свойства должны быть статическими?
т.е.
 
    public static float A_set
    {
     set { a = value; }
    }

Comment: Ни в коем случае. Статические (методы, свойства, поля) - значит связанные с *типом*, а не с *экземпляром* типа. А тут `UserControl1` это тип, а `userControl11` это его экземпляр, поэтому `a` и `b` содержатся именно в экземпляре.

Comment: Я написал:

             UserControl1 userControl11 = new UserControl1();
             userControl11.A_set = 6;
             userControl11.B_set = 3;
             userControl11.Am();

но все равно суммирования не происходит

Comment: Как я указал в ответе, не нужно создавать *новый* `UserControl1`, если есть уже созданный в редакторе форм - `userControl11`. Редактор форм во вспомогательном файле `Form1.designer.cs` в методе `InitializeComponent()` создаёт все компоненты формы. Можете его открыть и убедиться сами.

Comment: Спасибо! Заглянул во вспомогательный файл. Убедился. Теперь действительно работает